# Not Disable the entire screen during ajax request

Tags: primefaces

I want not show blocked screen with its gif, for every ajax call, I want to prevent this behaviour for some compoments and events like this:

```
 <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="checking" value="#{data.selected}">
            <p:ajax   update=":fG:pG" listener="#{backBean.selecteData(dato,cont)}"  event="change"  />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using a `p:ajaxStatus`.

In that case you can use `global="false"` to avoid triggering the ajaxStatus.

For example:

```
<p:ajax global="false"... />
<p:commandButton global="false"... />
```

Edit: For me it works in Primefaces 6.1, but not in 5.3 (even though it was documented in the docs). Haven't tested 6.0.

Comment: Hi I updated my question I used h:selectBooleanCheckbox and p:selectBooleanCheckbox and none have the global="false" property and I tried in the p:ajax and the same result,  and yes,  I have p:ajaxStatus in my template. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what Primefaces version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Jaqen H'ghar Primefaces 6.0